# Duality in abelian categories.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $C$ be an abelian category, with a projective separator $k$.
Assume that $C$ has a duality, that's a functor $\ast:C\to C^{\text{op}}$ together with a natural isomorphism $\tau:1\to \ast\ast$ such that $\tau_V^\ast=\tau_{V^\ast}^{-1}$ for each object $V$.

Let $q:V\to V^{*}$ be a morphism; $q$ can be interpreted as a bilinear form on $V$. To say that $q=q^{\ast}\circ \tau_V$ means that $q$ is symmetric.

Question: is true that each $q:k\to k^\ast$ is symmetric?

Remark: The answer to the question is yes in $R$-(left) modules category with $R$ a field (pheraps also if $R$ is commutative unitary ring) with $V^\ast=\text{Hom}(V,R)$. If $R$ is not commutative, then $V^\ast=\text{Hom}(V,R)$ is not a $R$-(left) module, hence $V\mapsto V^\ast$ doesn't define a duality in the sense of previous definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that this is true for (finite-dimensional) vector spaces over a field, but it is not!  It is true if $k$ happens to be the field itself, but that's not the only projective generator.  Indeed, any nonzero vector space is a projective generator.  So, if you choose $k$ to be a vector space of dimension greater than 1, then not every $q:k\to k^*$ is symmetric.